# Is there an easy way to convert from array to arrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am writing a class that has an arrayList that holds objects as a data member and for one of the methods in this class I have to convert it into a basic array. To achieve this I created a new array and used the .toArray() method. Now at the end of this method I have to put it back into the original arrayList. It appears that array doesn't have a .toArrayList(). I'm just wondering what the most simple way to convert would be. Thanks for any help.

Edit: forgot to say what the arrayList was holding (objects)

Comment: `Arrays.asList`?  You can then use `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(...))` or `anInstanceOfList.addAll(Arrays.asList(...))` depending on your needs

Comment: All sounds very inefficient. Why do you have to convert from ArrayList to an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new ArrayList<Element>(Arrays.asList(array))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the array type, but assuming it's an array of object(s) (as opposed to primitives) you could use [`Arrays.asList(T...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) like

```
String[] arr = {"Hello", "World"};
List<String> al = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Comment: (I believe the OP wants an instance of `ArrayList` at the end ;))

Comment: Will this work? since asList really just returns a List view of the array?